# The value send by a USB barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I know the scanner works as a keyboard and the event is treated as a key pressed down but nothing is happening.

I'm trying to get the value send by the barcode scanner to my activity to work with but none of the onKey events doesen't seem to be called when i press the button on the scanner.

I need the code to be passed down somehow for me to store it so i'd prefer not working with EditText.

Comment: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: @MartinZeitler So android cant get that code without help?

Comment: of course you need to filter for usb devices, in order to input somehow.